# Core Data sorting and don't display duplicates

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I'm new to core data and having some difficulty finding any information about sorting and only fetching non duplicates of a specified attribute.

I have a list of locations and they all have different addresses but some have the same city. i would like to fetch all the cities excluding duplicate cities and in alphabetical order.

Would the best way be to have 2 attributes, one for city and another for locationDetails. in the city attribute it will just have a list of cities with no duplicates and when selecting a city it will fetch all the locationDetails for that city attribute?

Thanks,

Comment: Read [Pro Core Data For iOS](http://www.apress.com/9781430233558) for a very in depth tutorial based book on core data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the best way will be to have a separate attribute for city. And you don't need to structure your entity as unique. You can take care of sorting and fetching unique in your fetch request.

```
NSFetchRequest *request=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"<your entity name>" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"City"]];
request.sortDescriptors=[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"City" ascending:YES]];
[request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
```

Note: This request returns an array of dictionaries with City as its key. Don't forget to release the NSFetchRequest after executing the fetch.

EDIT

When the user clicks on a city, store it in some variable (cityName). Now execute another fetch request like:

```
request.predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"City = %@",cityName];
```

You should do this with the same entity. This will fetch only the objects whose city name has been selected. Now, you can either do the fetch in 2 ways:

1. Fetch the entire entities and then dispay using the format
   `entityName.Location`. In this case you will get an NSArray of
   objects
2. Set the properties to fetch like:

   ```
   [request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Location"]];
   ```

In the second case, it returns a NSDictionary ( Don't forget to set Result Type as NSDictionaryResultType as before ).

Comment: with the array of dictionaries how would you know how many locations are associated with the city? I will need to display a list of cities and when they select a city it will display a list of locations if there is more than one. if there is just one then display the detailed locations view. 

Looks like the only way to get a list of objects from core data is to get it to return it as a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You should structure your Core Data model so that you have a City entity for each unique city and a Location entity with a one-to-one relationship to the relevant City entity (and a one-to-many reverse relationship). The city name itself should not be part of the Location entity. When structured this way, you simply fetch all City entities.

As for sorting, you should add a `NSSortDescriptor` to your `NSFetchRequest`. For example:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sorter;
sorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"name" ascending: YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: sortDescriptor]];
```